# Echarts график, цвет линии факта в зависимости от линии плана (visualmap)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Возник такой момент. На графике есть линия плана (синияя) и фактическая линия (белая).
Нужно участок фактической линии красить белым цветом, если участок выше плана, а если участок ниже плана, то красить красным цветом.

Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь легко так как линия плана прямая и идет с одним значением.

А бывают ситуации, когда линия плана не прямая. И в этом случае возникает проблема, как участки фактической линии красить. (в этом случае понятно что она вся красная должна быть). Но, если участок лини перейдет выше плана, то как это сделать? Есть варианты? Подскажите пожалуйста. В общем нужно чтобы фактическая линия зависела от плановой линии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]